# Threads - simple concurrency issue

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok this is the problem: the following code is obviously not written thread safe, cause the method increment() is not syncronized. The output varies, and doesn't go like: 1,2,3,4,5,6...

For example the output can be this: 1,2,3,4,5,1...
but then it continues like this 6,7,8,... and reaches 100. I don't understand how can it reach 100, shouldnt after second 1 come 2 again, at least in some cases, couse the balance was wrongly updated by the other thread. The question is this: why after 1 it continues normally with 6, 7...

```
class Job implements Runnable{
private int balance;

public void run(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        increment();
        System.out.println(balance);
        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;
        a = b;
    }

}

public void increment(){
    int i = balance;
    balance = i+1;
}
}

public class ThreadsDemo{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Job job = new Job();

    Thread alpha = new Thread(job);
    Thread beta = new Thread(job);

    alpha.setName("alpha");
    beta.setName("beta");

    alpha.start();
    beta.start();

}
}
```

To explain further, here is one of the possible outcomes:

Thread 1:
balance - 0

i - 0 (thread 1 put back to runnable)

Thread 2:
balance - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

i - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, (thread 2 put back to runnable)

Thread 1 (put to running):
balance - ... 1, **2**

i - 0, 1

(In some cases it can update normaly, but in 50 iterations it must come some abnormal update)
How does every outcome reach 100, is this some IDE optimization to deal with thread interleaving or what?

---

ANSWER:
So no need for latch in this example, just that the thread was "blocking" on print, and the other could finish the update in the meantime. Ty Affe

```
class Job implements Runnable{
public int balance = 0;
//public static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public void run(){

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            increment();
        }
}

public void increment(){
    int i = balance;
    balance = i+1;
}
}

public class ThreadsDemo{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Job job = new Job();

    Thread alpha = new Thread(job);
    Thread beta = new Thread(job);

    alpha.setName("alpha");
    beta.setName("beta");

    alpha.start();
    beta.start();

    try {
        alpha.join();
                    beta.join();
    } catch (Exception ex) { }
    System.out.println(job.balance +"   "+ alpha.isAlive() + "    " + beta.isAlive());
}
}
```

The output is around 60 000, as it was expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculation is very fast and starting threads is very slow.  The first one is completely done before the second one ever begins.  The out-of-place numbers in the output are likely just issues with buffer flushing in the operating system.

Add a latch so that both threads actually start at the same time, and use a sufficiently large number, and you will see a total that doesn't add up.

```
public static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
private static class Job implements Runnable{
private int balance;

public void run(){
    try {
    latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        //existing code
    }
}
public void increment(){
    int i = balance;
    //make it work harder so there's more opportunity for an actual interleave
    balance = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(i)).add(BigInteger.ONE).intValue();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //existing code
    alpha.start();
    beta.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    latch.countDown();

}
```

Comment: Im implementing it now.

Comment: Note that the reason for why you may see the same number printed out more than once is that it is entirely possible that the execution runs `increment()` twice in a row, followed by running `print` twice in a row (albeit printing to different buffers).

Comment: Ok, i put a latch (even if i dont understand it), and it allways adds up to 100 000, (once to 99 999), it should have bigger differencies, dont you think so. The threads should interleave, and make wrong result. How is it possible that i come with the correct result every time? How can i put the corrected code in the comment.

Comment: Would not really expect a difference larger than 1 or 2, no.  How long do you think it takes a modern computer to count to 50,000?  Need to do something more complicated in there to see larger differences.  See edit.

Comment: Incidentally you are also significantly reducing the number of interleaves by making them print the number on every pass.  That is a long slow operation that they both have to stop and wait on, so there's not a lot of chance to both be in increment at the same time, generally one will be in increment while the other is waiting on println.  If you just print the balance once at the end you'll see a number that is off by a much larger amount.

Comment: Oh, i did print only at the end. And it went of by a large amount. Must be what you said that, they "block" on print most of the time, while other thread finish the update.
Sorry for late answer, i was on the phone.

Comment: Depends on how big `i` is.  With the latch you can use a value as small as 50 and still see errors when moving println to the end.  Without the latch you won't consistently see errors until it's a few orders larger.